# Replaced FX 4300 with FX 4350, motherboard claims it to be incompatible

Tags: cpu, motherboard, cpu-speed

My friend got a FX 4350 and replaced his FX 4300, the gigabyte GA-78LMT-S2 motherboard is now claiming the old CPU is incompatible and it underclocks it, completely removing the purpose of using the new CPU, it also disables two CPU cores, the other FX works perfectly. Any idea what is causing this? It's undercooked to 2.7ghz from 4.2 stock without our doing so, it is just the motherboard. We have also reset the bios settings

Comment: Your friend is using the current revision of the firmware, that specifically, indicates support for the replacement CPU?

Comment: I believe so,CAM says the BIOS was from. 2014 and that was the latest year from the gigabyte BIOS update. As for supporting it the BIOS tells us it isn't supported

Comment: You need to verify.  I cannot answer your question, if you only believe, the firmware is current.  You don't mention the motherboard model, so i am unable to verify, if the CPU is even supported with any firmware revision.

Comment: [According to Gigabyte](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/cpu-support.aspx), the closest model that's compatible with that processor is "GA-78LMT-S2PV (rev. 5.0)", where as the earlier versions (ie: GA-78LMT-S2 (rev. 1.0)) support the 4300.  So which exact model and revision number is the board you're trying to use?

Comment: @Ramhound it is running the latest BIOS

Comment: @Techie007 motherboard revision 1.2

Comment: The motherboard in question, unless it's revision 5, does not support the FX 4350.  Your friend should return the FX 4350 and get their money back.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, thanks. Just to check though, do you think it would be a bad idea to try and force the 4350 to run at its full speed?

Comment: @bennottelling - You won't be able to.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, thank you for the help. Better a supported CPU that runs at full speed than a unsupported fhat runs at half the speed and cores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GA-78LMT-S2 (rev. 1.2)](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4643&dl=1#sp) does not support the FX 4350

[image]

Source: [GA-78LMT-S2 (rev. 1.2) CPU Compatability List](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/cpu-support-popup.aspx?pid=4643)